# How do you center text in a textbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Hi trying to center some text in a textbox in Google Slides using Apps Script. However it doesn't work. Not sure what the current function is for this. Can't find answers online. Please help.

```
var id = template.makeCopy(rows[i][0] + ' ' + rows[i][1],destination).getId(),
      slide = SlidesApp.openById(id).getSlides()[0],
      shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 205, 130, 300, 60),
      textRange = shape.getText(),
      textStyle = textRange.getTextStyle();

  textRange.setText([rows[i][0] + ' ' + rows[i][1]]);
  textStyle.setFontSize(40);
  textStyle.setForegroundColor('#F9B300');
  textStyle.setTextAlignment(SlidesApp.TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed the code using [Apps script's sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/editing-styling#text_styling):

```
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 50, 50, 300, 300);
var textRange = shape.getText();
textRange.setText('Paragraph 1\nParagraph2\nParagraph 3\nParagraph 4');
var paragraphs = textRange.getParagraphs();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var paragraphStyle = paragraphs[i].getRange().getParagraphStyle();
  paragraphStyle.setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
}
```

I tried using `getTextStyle();` but there is no `setTextAlignment`. I noticed that in the Apps Script Sample code they use getText() just for setting the text or styling the text and used `getParagraphStyle()` to set the style for the item like alignment and other paragraph related styling.

[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: The great example above solves horizontal alignment of text in a text box. Has anyone discovered a way to vertically align?

Comment: Also how does this work when creating the text box with batch update?